# put data from jquery to google map javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

am struggling the last 3 hours
am trying to update my google maps markers positions from database without refresh the page so the user can track updated movement 
i used jquery to extract all the data from database from page called data.php that give me everything i need to type it directly into the javascript code to add the markers.

but when i put  or

inside the javascript initialization function everything is not working
so i don't know how to get the html.(output).show to div without crashing the whole code

here is the code of the page that i want to display google markers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>GLOBAL CLEANERS</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get()
        {
          $.post('data.php',function(output)
          {$('#age').html(output).show();}
                  );

        } 
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {

  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.3146996,44.3772661);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  var image = 'zbala.png';

<?php echo '<div id="age">var myLatlng500 = new google.maps.LatLng(33.3146996,44.3772661);</div>'; ?>

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// ??? ????? ????? ???? ???????


    </script>

  </head>
  <body bgcolor="002022">
  <form name="form"><input type="button" name="submit-button"value="submit-button"onclick="get();"></form>

  <img src="logo-global.jpg"  style="height: 100px;width:90%;position: absolute;left:150px;top:0%; opacity: 1.0;"/>
  <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%px;top: 100px;left:150px"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand why you are PHP-injecting a line of HTML into the middle of your javascript

Comment: yes you find the position of my problem... in this div the data is printed as output from the other page to be joined with the javascript code to add the new markers position , but no matter how i added it always the page have us error on display unless i remove this div but it's too important cause it get the updated position markers from the gps

Comment: You don't need php but you need to put this on jsfiddle to make it clear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: is there any code or links about such similar problem ??